# Insomnia integration with xray and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, web-api-testing, insomnia, jira-xray

Just a question about insomnia API testing, is it possible to run the tests integrated with jenkins and jira xray?

There doesn't seem to be a lot of information about how to run the tests automated or if its possible to integrate with xray (needed for audit purposes).

Answer (score 1):

To run the tests with Insomnia you can use the [`inso` CLI tool](https://docs.insomnia.rest/inso-cli/introduction).

```bash
inso run test
```

The challenge is that inso doesn't provide a way to generate a reporter that Xray can handle, such as the popular JUnit XML report format.
There has been some discussion on the [Insomnia community project](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/3059) to provide custom reporters, like the mocha-junit-reporter, but it is not yet possible.

`inso` can produce a "spec" kind of reporter, using the default `spec` reporter. One way to move forward would be to convert that output to a JUnit XML report. Then, to submit the JUnit XML report would be possible using the [Jenkins plugin](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integration+with+Jenkins), or even by invoking Xray's REST API and submiting it to the [Junit XML specific endpoint](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-JUnitXMLresults).

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u admin:admin -F "file=@report.xml" http://yourserver/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/junit?projectKey=XTP
```